# WPF Custom ComboBox Control

Tags: wpf, controls

I am using a ComboBox in my WPF application. The ComboBox has a scrolling issue that was introduced in the .NET Framework. I looked online for a solution and found that I need to create a new ComboBox that overrides **OnApplyTemplate()** and **GetVisualChild((DependencyObject reference))** and introduces some new logic to fix the issue in these methods.

See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0a571c75-4976-4c94-a59e-b085679a5d08/

My question, is simply, what type of control do you reckon I should create?

1. Custom Control
2. User Control
3. Inherited from CoboBox Class - just simply create a new class that derives from ComboBox and add the methods above?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is #3, which is what is done in the link you provided. For #1, you'd have to duplicate all of the ComboBox control code and I'm not sure you could do it with #2.

Comment: Great. Thanks for this. I am happy to go with #3. Although, I'm a little confused on #1? You say that the control code needs to be duplicated. Does this mean that I need to create overridden `DependencyProperty` properties for each of the properties exposed in the ComboBox or do you mean that I need to somehow grab source code from the ComboBox and implement in my new custom control?

Comment: @Finbar - Yes, you'd need to duplicate all the code that is in the ComboBox class, then tweak it to fix the issue you describe. Atleast, that's what I'm assuming you meant by #1 (i.e. a MyComboBox control that works exactly like ComboBox but fixes your issue).

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean. Just to confirm - if you don't mind. Do you mean "Duplicate by overriding each property explicitly" or "Duplicate by getting source and copy/paste _reimplementing_"?

Comment: @Finbar - You would have to get the source and reimplement it. You can't simply "override each property explicitly" to get the same functionality.